# How to use function with 2 dataframes in python

Tags: python, pandas

I have to execute an script within a function where 2 dataframes are being used.

When working separately it works well but i am not getting how to use the function where we have to deal with 2 dataframes.

Need Suggestion

```
df1 = pd.read_excel(open(r'input.xlsx', 'rb'), sheet_name='sheet1')
df2 = pd.read_excel(open(r'input.xlsx', 'rb'), sheet_name='sheet2')
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz 

cross = df1[['id_number']].merge(df2[['identity_no']], how='cross')
cross['match'] = cross.apply(lambda x: fuzz.ratio(x.id_number, x.identity_no), axis=1)
df1['match_acc'] = df1.id_number.map(cross.groupby('id_number').match.max())
```

**I need to execute the above script within a function.**

I have tried using the below code but not getting how a function can be used where we have to use 2 dataframes.

```
def word(x,y):
   try:
      cross = x[['id_number']].merge(y[['identity_no']], how='cross')
      cross['match'] = cross.apply(lambda x: fuzz.ratio(x.id_number, x.identity_no), axis=1)
      x['match_acc'] = x.id_number.map(cross.groupby('id_number').match.max())
   return ValueError:
      x['status'] = ValueError

   return x

df = df.apply(word, axis=1)
```

Please Suggest.

Comment: Add a couple of rows from both of the dataframes and add the expected output to the question.

Comment: @ThePyGuy - I have edited the question , Please suggest how 2 dataframes can be executed within a function.

Comment: @Corralien- "AXN pvt Ltd" company is  "IN2231D", I am trying to find the accuracy by matching with Dataframe 2 . The First script is working fine , My concern is how can i use both the dataframe in a function . Please Suggest.

Comment: `Try / return` does not exist: replace by `Try / except`

Comment: @Corralien -  My mistake . Yes it would be except instead of return . Thanks for bringing to my concern., Please suggest how i can use the script inside an function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question, I used the `process` module from `fuzzywuzzy` package.

```py
from fuzzywuzzy import process

df1["match_acc"] = df1["id_number"].apply(
    lambda x: process.extractOne(x, df2["identity_no"])[1])
```

```py
>>> df1
  id_number          company_name  match_acc
0   IN2231D           AXN pvt Ltd         92
1   UK654IN        Aviva Intl Ltd        100
2   SL1432H   Ship Incorporations         92
3   LK0678G  Oppo Mobiles pvt ltd        100
4   NG5678J             Nokia Inc         43
```

**Edit**: *"create the logic within a function"*

```py
def word(x, y):
    x["match_acc"] = process.extractOne(x["id_number"], y["identity_no"])[1]
    return x

out = df1.apply(word, y=df2, axis=1)
```

```
>>> out
  id_number          company_name  match_acc
0   IN2231D           AXN pvt Ltd         92
1   UK654IN        Aviva Intl Ltd        100
2   SL1432H   Ship Incorporations         92
3   LK0678G  Oppo Mobiles pvt ltd        100
4   NG5678J             Nokia Inc         43
```

Comment: Logic is working fine , Actually i want to create the logic within a function For Eg inside : "def test(x,y):" and return the output value which i can apply later in the datarame. Please find the reference in the above Question.

Comment: I updated my answer. I hope this is what you need!