# Map values from another dataframe within multiple conditions

Tags: python, pandas

Looking to map highest matching row values from Dataframe2 to Dataframe1 using conditions. We also need to check df1['sal_date'] between df2['from'] and df['to'] .

Want to compare each row(df1['id_number']) from df1 with the whole column(df2['identity_No']) of df2. I have applied using partial match for extracting the condition and its working,

**But how i can check if df1['sal_date'] falls which of the  df2['from'] and df['to'] .**

**df1**

```
score   id_number       company_name      company_code        sal_date     action_reqd
20      IN2231D           AXN pvt Ltd        IN225           2019-12-22        Yes
45      UK654IN        Aviva Intl Ltd        IN115           2018-10-10        No
65      SL1432H   Ship Incorporations        CZ555           2015-08-19        Yes
35      LK0678G  Oppo Mobiles pvt ltd        PQ795           2018-06-26        Yes
59      NG5678J             Nokia Inc        RS885           2020-12-28        No
20      IN2231D           AXN pvt Ltd        IN215           2020-12-08        Yes
```

**df2**

```
OR_score   identity_No       comp_name        comp_code   dte_from        dte_to
51          UK654IN        Aviva Int.L Ltd       IN515    2017-12-05    2018-10-13
25          SL6752J       Ship Inc Traders       CZ555    2013-08-07    2022-06-21
79          NG5678K             Nokia Inc        RS005    2018-10-13    2019-12-15
51          UK654IN        Aviva Int.L Ltd       IN525    2018-12-15    2020-12-24
20          IN22312           AXN pvt Ltd        IN255    2019-12-10    2022-06-21
79          NG5678K             Nokia Inc        RS055    2019-06-08    2024-12-30
38          LK0665G       Oppo Mobiles ltd       PQ895    2016-10-10    2022-12-08
20          IN22312           AXN pvt Ltd        IN275    2017-08-17    2018-10-13
75          NG5678K             Nokia Inc        RS055    2013-06-08    2016-12-30
```

> df1.id_number need to be compared with df2.identity_No and df1.sal_date must be between df2.from and df2.to .

Looking to match based on row1 of df1['id_number'] will match across all rows of df2['identity_No'], and has highest match percentage wrt. row4 of df2['identity_No'] , and its more than 80%, and df1.sal_date is between df2.from and df2.to.

> it will copy the respective values from row4 of df2 to row1 of df1.
> same to be applied for each row of df1.

**Expected Output:**

```
score   id_number       company_name      company_code          match_acc     action_reqd
20      IN22312           AXN pvt Ltd        IN255              2019-12-22          Yes
51      UK654IN       Aviva Int.L Ltd        IN515              2018-10-10          No
25      SL1432H   Ship Incorporations        CZ555              2015-08-19          Yes
38      LK0665G      Oppo Mobiles ltd        PQ795              2018-06-26          Yes
79      NG5678K             Nokia Inc        RS055              2020-12-28          No
20      IN22312           AXN pvt Ltd        IN255              2020-12-08          Yes
```

I have tried this now:

```
for index, row in df1.iterrows():
    for index2, config2 in df2.iterrows():
        variable = fuzz.partial_ratio(row['id_number'], config2['identity_No'])
        if variable>=80:
            df1['id_number'][index] = config2['identity_No']
            df1['company_name'][index] = config2['comp_name']
            df1['company_code'][index] = config2['comp_code']
            df1['score'][index] = config2['OR_Score']
```

> How can i execute the remaining code after if condition as variable >=80% and df1.sal_date is between df2.from and df2.to

Please Suggestm How it can be executed.

Comment: What if df1['id_number']  matches more than 80% with 2 or more df2['identity_No']?

Comment: @Ank - Along with checking for the matches more than 80% ,  we also need to check df1['sal_date'] is between df2['from'] and df2['to'] .

Comment: yeah that I understood, what if after applying both these conditions a row in df1 maps  to 2 or more rows in df2?

Comment: Or is it sure that after applying both those conditions, there will be 1:1 mapping only?

Comment: @Ank - When we will apply,  row1 of df1['id_number'] will match across all rows of df2['identity_No'], and has highest match percentage wrt. row4 of df2['identity_No'] , and its more than 80%, and df1.sal_date is between df2.from and df2.to. We will be having 1:1 mapping only, Same need to be done for each row of df1['id_number'].

Comment: If no row can be dropped from df1 and you only return the best match based on your conditions, i.e. there truly is 1:1 mapping, how does the 80% threshold matter? IMO your first condition is: `dte_from <= sal_date <= dte_to` and then you simply pick the df2 row with the highest match percentage, no?

Comment: @NicMoetsch - Getting the error with Suggested code TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'float'

Comment: Oh yeah, no that was just the mathematical equation sorry. Was just trying to figure out if that logic is sufficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has two main flaws:

1. Going by your description of the problem (below), whether or not `df1['sal_date']` is between `dte_from` and `dte_to` is the necessary condition and thus should be checked first. The second step is returning the highest possible match. Since you want to force 1:1 mapping, the match being `>=80` doesn't matter, you simply return the highest one.

> Looking to map highest matching row values from Dataframe2 to Dataframe1 using conditions. We also need to check df1['sal_date'] between df2['from'] and df['to'].

2. Your code doesn't really return the row from `df2` with the highest match percentage over 80%, but it returns the last one. Every time the condition `variable>=80` is met, the current current row in `df1` is overwritten.

also, the name for column 1 in `df2` is inconsistent; in `df2` it's called `OR_score` with lowercase `s` but in the code it's called `OR_Score` with capital `S`.

I changed your code a little bit. I added `highest_match`, which keeps track of what the `variable` of the highest match was and only overwrites if the new match's `variable` is higher than the highest match. This resets for each row if `df1`.

I dont use `>=` thus it keeps the first match if `variable` is equal. If you want to keep your `>=80` condition, you can initialize `highest_match = 80`, however this code want warn you if for one row of `df1` no match `>=80` is found and the row thus just stays as it was.

The code also only proceeds, if the date condition is met first.

```
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz

for index, row in df1.iterrows():
    highest_match = 0
    for index2, config2 in df2.iterrows():
        cond1 = df1['sal_date'][index] <= config2['dte_to']
        cond2 = df1['sal_date'][index] >= config2['dte_from']
        if cond1 and cond2:
            variable = fuzz.partial_ratio(row['id_number'], config2['identity_No'])
            if variable > highest_match:
                df1['id_number'][index] = config2['identity_No']
                df1['company_name'][index] = config2['comp_name']
                df1['company_code'][index] = config2['comp_code']
                df1['score'][index] = config2['OR_score']
                highest_match = variable
```

This code is not optimized for time complexity, it just does what you were trying to accomplish. Or atleast it produces your expected output.. Adding the `>=80` constraint might improve time, but then you'll need to add some logic for what should happen if no match is `>=80`.

Please add your code of how the tables are created as well the next time and not just the output. That makes recreating your problem much easier and more people would be willing to help, thanks.

EDIT:

If youn want to keep rows with missing `sal_date` simply skip them:

```
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz

for index, row in df1.iterrows():
    if pd.isna(row['sal_date']):
        continue
    highest_match = 0
    for index2, config2 in df2.iterrows():
        cond1 = df1['sal_date'][index] <= config2['dte_to']
        cond2 = df1['sal_date'][index] >= config2['dte_from']
        if cond1 and cond2:
            variable = fuzz.partial_ratio(row['id_number'], config2['identity_No'])
            if variable > highest_match:
                df1['id_number'][index] = config2['identity_No']
                df1['company_name'][index] = config2['comp_name']
                df1['company_code'][index] = config2['comp_code']
                df1['score'][index] = config2['OR_score']
                highest_match = variable
```

Comment: When there is any blank / NaN values, the error occurs.  TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'float' and 'str'

Comment: Ok, this is not really a stackoverflow problem then, you just need to figure out what you want to do with missing data. If there is no `dte_to`, do you assume is is still going on? Then you'd set `dte_to` to `pd.Timestamp.now()`. If you want to make a worst case assumption, you'd need to set it to `dte_from`. Ultimately these questions can only be answered from your domain expertise. I'd urge you to fill the missing data with values that make sense and then run the code. You could add logic to the code to handel this but that's not how i personally would go about the problem.

Comment: In the above case, i am having cases where df1['sal_date'] having the NaN values as well, i want to skip on the rows where df1['sal_date'] = NaN,  How i can handle the NaN values as it gives the Error: TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'float' and 'str'

Comment: I have tried changing cond1 = df1['sal_date'][index] <= config2['dte_to'] to if row['sal_date'].isna() == False: cond1 = df1['sal_date'][index] <= config2['dte_to'], But its not working.

Comment: @nkj if you don't have a `sal_date` what do you wish happen? You could simply filter df1 to only keep rows that have a `sal_date`: df1.dropna(subset=['sal_date'], inplace=True)

Comment: Sir, Thanks , I have posted an another question having the detailed requirement "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67691428/typeerror-not-supported-between-instances-of-float-and-str#67691744" Need your suggestion on that.

Comment: @NKJ chek the edit, should do what you are showing in the expected output of the other question.