# TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'float' and 'str'

Tags: python, pandas

Looking to map highest matching row values from Dataframe2 to Dataframe1 using conditions. We also need to check `df1['sal_date']` between `df2['from']` and `df['to']`.

**df1**

```
score   id_number       company_name      company_code        sal_date     action_reqd
20      IN2231D           AXN pvt Ltd        IN225           2019-12-22        Yes
45      UK654IN        Aviva Intl Ltd        IN115           2018-10-10        No
65      SL1432H   Ship Incorporations        CZ555           2015-08-19        Yes
35      LK0678G  Oppo Mobiles pvt ltd        PQ795           2018-06-26        Yes
59      NG5678J             Nokia Inc        RS885           2020-12-28        No
59      NG5678J             Nokia Inc        RS885                             No
20      IN2231D           AXN pvt Ltd        IN215           2020-12-08        Yes
```

df2
**df2**

```
OR_score   identity_No       comp_name        comp_code   dte_from        dte_to
51          UK654IN        Aviva Int.L Ltd       IN515    2017-12-05    2018-10-13
25          SL6752J       Ship Inc Traders       CZ555    2013-08-07    2022-06-21
79          NG5678K             Nokia Inc        RS005    2018-10-13    2019-12-15
51          UK654IN        Aviva Int.L Ltd       IN525    2018-12-15    2020-12-24
20          IN22312           AXN pvt Ltd        IN255    2019-12-10    2022-06-21
79          NG5678K             Nokia Inc        RS055    2019-06-08    2024-12-30
38          LK0665G       Oppo Mobiles ltd       PQ895    2016-10-10    2022-12-08
20          IN22312           AXN pvt Ltd        IN275    2017-08-17    2018-10-13
75          NG5678K             Nokia Inc        RS055    2013-06-08    2016-12-30
```

The script to execute the function is working fine, But when
`df1['sal_date']` value is NaN it doesn't works and gives error:

**Expected Output:**

```
score   id_number       company_name      company_code          sal_date     action_reqd     comments
20      IN22312           AXN pvt Ltd        IN255              2019-12-22          Yes
51      UK654IN       Aviva Int.L Ltd        IN515              2018-10-10          No
25      SL1432H   Ship Incorporations        CZ555              2015-08-19          Yes
38      LK0665G      Oppo Mobiles ltd        PQ795              2018-06-26          Yes
79      NG5678K             Nokia Inc        RS055              2020-12-28          No
59      NG5678J             Nokia Inc        RS885                                  No        Sal_date is not available 
20      IN22312           AXN pvt Ltd        IN255              2020-12-08          Yes
```

**Code i was using:**

```
for index, row in df1.iterrows():
    highest_match = 0
    for index2, config2 in df2.iterrows():
        cond1 = df1['sal_date'][index] >= config2['dte_to']
        cond2 = df1['sal_date'][index] <= config2['dte_from']
        if cond1 and cond2:
            variable = fuzz.partial_ratio(row['id_number'], config2['identity_No'])
            if variable > 80:
                df1['id_number'][index] = config2['identity_No']
                df1['company_name'][index] = config2['comp_name']
                df1['company_code'][index] = config2['comp_code']
                df1['score'][index] = config2['OR_score']
                highest_match = variable
```

I modified the script to below code but it's also not working:

```
for index, row in df1.iterrows():
    highest_match = 0
    for index2, config2 in df2.iterrows():
        if row['sal_Date'].isna() == False:
            cond1 = df1['sal_date'][index] >= config2['dte_to']
            cond2 = df1['sal_date'][index] <= config2['dte_from']
            if cond1 and cond2:
                variable = fuzz.partial_ratio(row['id_number'], config2['identity_No'])
                if variable > highest_match:
                    df1['id_number'][index] = config2['identity_No']
                    df1['company_name'][index] = config2['comp_name']
                    df1['company_code'][index] = config2['comp_code']
                    df1['score'][index] = config2['OR_score']
                    highest_match = variable
        else:
            df1['comments'][index] = 'Sal Date is not Available'
```

Please suggest how to handle NaN values

Comment: Have you considered fillna or dropna?

Comment: @DrakeMurdoch - I Can't use dropNa or FillNa, As we can see I have to execute the code on the columns "sal_Date" , if the rows are available , else need to update the column df['comments'] in from of each row with NaN values

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is that you need to convert the dates into UNIX, because Python just doesn not know how to compare dates. So, try to convert the date into a datetime.datetime object, and then into UNIX time:

```py
import datetime
import time

# Let's say, the date is:
date_string = '2019-12-22'

# We need to turn it into a list first:
date_tuple = date_string.split('-') 

# Make an Datetime object
datetime_object = datetime.datetime(int(date_tuple[0]), int(date_tuple[1]), int(date_tuple[2]))

# Then, convert it into UNIX timestamp:
unix = time.mktime(datetime_object.timetuple())

print(unix)
```

Then, you just need to compare it like you would normally.

**EDIT**

> I just need to check for if and else condition when there is any NaN value in df1["sal_Date"]

You can check if a variable has content or not using this:

```py
var1 = 'hello'
var2 = ''

if var1:
    print('var1 has content')
else:
    print('var1 is empty')

if var2:
    print('var2 has content')
else:
    print('var2 is empty')
```

**To check if there is any NaN value in a list:**

```
foods = ['Pizza', '', 'Apple']

for food in foods:
    if not food:
        print('There IS an empty element in the list.')
```

Comment: SIr, The Code in the Question is working , I just need to check for if and else condition when there is any NaN value in df1["sal_Date"], As we can see I have to execute the code on the columns "sal_Date" , if the rows are available , else need to update the column df['comments'] in from of each row with NaN values .

Comment: @Jacoblee - The Code in the Question is working if there is no NaN values , I just need to check for if and else condition when there is any NaN value in df1["sal_Date"], As we can see I have to execute the code on the columns "sal_Date" , if the rows are available , else need to update the column df['comments'] in from of each row with NaN values .

Comment: @NKJ Understood, but the content under **EDIT**, in blockquotes, was not by me.

Comment: @JacobLee -  Any suggestion on how to filter NaN values in df1["sal_Date"], and only execute the rest of the loop  on the not NaN values in df1["sal_Date"]. Using If Else condition Please Suggest.

Comment: @JacobLee just removed the line saying "If you found this answer useful, a upvote and mark as a question would be really appreciated <3".