# merge 2 dataframes based on partial string-match between columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two data frames df1 and df2 as shown below:

**Df1:**

```
                  movie    correct_id
0              birdman        N/A
1     avengers: endgame        N/A
2              deadpool        N/A
3  once upon deadpool        N/A
```

**Df2: data frame of reference**

```
          movie              correct_id
0               birdmans          4
1  The avengers: endgame          2
2               The King          3
3   once upon a deadpool          1
```

**Expected Result:**

```
            movie    correct_id
0              birdman        4
1     avengers: endgame       2
2             deadpool       N/A
3   once upon deadpool        1
```

Please how do I merge two dataframes based on partial string match?

**NB**: The movie's name not exactly the same

Comment: First you'll need to define precisely what you consider a partial string match. And what happened to The King?

Comment: The df2 i considered as a reference, the king doesnt exists in the reference. I mean that the movie's name not exactly the same. exp 'The avengers:endgame' in the ref (df2) but in df1 it is 'avengers:endgame'

Comment: Have a look to `fuzzywuzzy` or `rapidfuzz` to compute string distance and take for each key in `df1` to key in `df2` that minimizes levenstein distance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67627915/15239951).

Input data:

```
>>> df1
                movie  correct_id
0             birdman         NaN
1   avengers: endgame         NaN
2            deadpool         NaN
3  once upon deadpool         NaN

>>> df2
                   movie  correct_id
0               birdmans           4
1  The avengers: endgame           2
2               The King           3
3   once upon a deadpool           1
```

A bit of fuzzy logic:

```
from fuzzywuzzy import process

dfm = pd.DataFrame(df1["movie"].apply(lambda x: process.extractOne(x, df2["movie"]))
                               .tolist(), columns=["movie", "ratio", "best_id"])
```

```
>>> dfm
                            movie  ratio  best_id
0                        birdmans     93        0
1  The avengers: endgame: endgame     90        1
2            once upon a deadpool     90        3
3            once upon a deadpool     95        3
```

The index of `dfm` is the index of `df1` rather than the column `best_id` is the index of `df2`. Now you can update your first dataframe:

```
THRESHOLD = 90  # adjust this number

ids = dfm.loc[dfm["ratio"] > THRESHOLD, "best_id"]
df1["correct_id"] = df2.loc[ids, "correct_id"].astype("Int64")
```

```
>>> df1
                movie  correct_id
0             birdman           4
1   avengers: endgame           2
2            deadpool        <NA>
3  once upon deadpool           1
```

Comment: No, it's not possible, that was not the good result. Please, check my updated answer.

Comment: Actually the first one works verry well for me, But when i tried the updated answer, i got an error TypeError: object cannot be converted to an IntegerDtype

Comment: Remove `astype("Int64")` and see the result. What is your version of Pandas?