# How to search a substring from one df in another df?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48743662/python-pandas-merge-based-on-substring-in-string) and would like to do something similar.

I have 2 dfs:

df1:

| file_num | city | address_line |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Toronto | 123 Fake St |
| 2 | Montreal | 456 Sample Ave |

df2:

| DB_Num | Address |
| --- | --- |
| AB1 | Toronto 123 Fake St |
| AB3 | 789 Random Drive, Toronto |

I want to know which DB_Num in df2 match to addres_line and city in df1, and include which file_num the match was from.

My ideal output is:

| file_num | city | address_line | DB_Num | Address |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Toronto | 123 Fake St | AB1 | Toronto 123 Fake St |

Based on the above linked post, I have made a look ahead regex, and am searching using the `insert` and `str.extract` method.

```
df1['search_field'] = "(?=.*" + df1['city'] + ")(?=.*" + df1['address_line'] + ")"
pat = "|".join(df1['search_field'])
df = df2.insert(0, 'search_field', df2['Address'].str.extract("(" + pat + ')', expand=False))
```

Since my address in df2 is entered manually, it is sometimes out of order.

Because it is out of order, I am using the look ahead method of regex.

The look ahead method is causing `str.extract` to not output any value. Although I can still filter out nulls and it will keep only the correct matches.

My main problem is I have no way to join back to df1 to get the file_num.

I can do this problem with a for loop and iterating each record to search, but it takes too long. df1 is actually around 5000 records, and df2 has millions, so it takes over 2 hours to run. Is there a way to leverage vectorization for this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: I think you can't vectorize your operation but you can use `multiprocess` or `numba` or `Dask`. I think you should use [fuzzy logic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67837581/15239951) to merge your 2 dataframes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start by creating a new series which is the row each "Address" in df2 corresponds to "address_line" in df1, if such a row exists:

```
r = '({})'.format('|'.join(df1.address_line))
merge_df = df2.Address.str.extract(r, expand=False)
merge_df
```

#output:

```
0    123 Fake St
1            NaN
Name: Address, dtype: object
```

Now we merge our df1 on the "address_line" column, and our df2 on our "merge_df" series:

```
df1.merge(df2, left_on='address_line', right_on=merge_df)
```

| index | file_num | City | address_line | DB_num | Address |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1.0 | Toronto | 123 Fake St | AB1 | Toronto 123 Fake St |